# My AC's internal unit throws water droplets when started

Tags: air-conditioning, leak

So, Summer is upon us in Palestine/Israel for a number of weeks now, and I've started using my (split-system) AC to cool the room again.

Unfortunately, in recent days, when I start the AC - the inner unit (installed above me) throws a few water droplets, just when it starts running. Now, it doesn't continue doing that, but still - it's annoying when they hit me! ... and I don't remember this happening last year.

My questions:

- What causes this phenomenon? (Ok, obviously condensation and humidity; I mean what *exactly* is going on)
- Is there something that I can do myself to mitigate it (or fix it)?

Notes:

- It's very humid where I live (Haifa) - typically around 80% these days.
- In case it matters - I cleaned my filters about a month back.
- This AC unit is in an apartment I rent, so I don't know exactly how old it is, but - it should be somewhere between 8 and 15, I figure.
- If a photo of some of the innards would help, ask.

Comment: Have you checked the drain - sounds like water is getting trapped.

Comment: i bet the thing is dusty, which makes it run colder, which means it's still cold enough to be condensing water (or at least recently enough to be wet) when it turns back on. I had one like that, but cleaning the coils, grill and "ducts" fixed the problem, though it was a messy job.

Comment: @SolarMike: Doesn't the drain only drain the outer unit?

Comment: Check, bet there is water pooling on that internal unit...

Comment: You have it reversed. The only place water is produced is the inside unit. It condenses on the evaporator (refrigeration) coils in the air handler and is conducted away in a tube going outside. Your drain tube may need cleaning.